# Cannot get Git tab to show up in RStudio

Tags: r, github, devtools, r-package, r-usethis

I've looked through a bunch of links so far, but so far none of them seems to solve my issue with installing the `usethis` package or getting my Git tab to work in R. For context, my `session_info` is below and I have just downloaded R and RStudio (along with restarting my session from scratch):

```
setting  value
 version  R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt)
 os       Windows 11 x64 (build 22621)
 system   x86_64, mingw32
 ui       RStudio
 language (EN)
 collate  Chinese (Simplified)_China.utf8
 ctype    Chinese (Simplified)_China.utf8
 tz       Asia/Shanghai
 date     2023-05-23
 rstudio  2023.03.1+446 Cherry Blossom (desktop)
 pandoc   NA

─ Packages ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package     * version date (UTC) lib source
 cachem        1.0.8   2023-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 callr         3.7.3   2022-11-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 cli           3.6.0   2023-01-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 crayon        1.5.2   2022-09-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 devtools    * 2.4.5   2022-10-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 digest        0.6.31  2022-12-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 ellipsis      0.3.2   2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 fastmap       1.1.1   2023-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 fs            1.6.1   2023-02-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 glue          1.6.2   2022-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 htmltools     0.5.5   2023-03-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 htmlwidgets   1.6.2   2023-03-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 httpuv        1.6.11  2023-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 later         1.3.1   2023-05-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 lifecycle     1.0.3   2022-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 magrittr      2.0.3   2022-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 memoise       2.0.1   2021-11-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 mime          0.12    2021-09-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 miniUI        0.1.1.1 2018-05-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 pkgbuild      1.4.0   2022-11-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 pkgload       1.3.2   2022-11-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 prettyunits   1.1.1   2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 processx      3.8.0   2022-10-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 profvis       0.3.8   2023-05-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 promises      1.2.0.1 2021-02-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 ps            1.7.2   2022-10-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 purrr         1.0.1   2023-01-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 R6            2.5.1   2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 Rcpp          1.0.10  2023-01-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 remotes       2.4.2   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 rlang         1.0.6   2022-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 rstudioapi    0.14    2022-08-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 shiny         1.7.4   2022-12-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 stringi       1.7.12  2023-01-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 stringr       1.5.0   2022-12-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 urlchecker    1.0.1   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 usethis     * 2.1.6   2022-05-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 vctrs         0.5.2   2023-01-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 xtable        1.8-4   2019-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)

 [1] E:/R-4.3.0/library
```

When I run `library(devtools)`, I consistently get the following message:

```
载入需要的程辑包：usethis
```

Which basically says I still need to install the `usethis` package. However, I have already installed this package, and it is clearly visible in my packages tab:

[image]

I have tried updating both `usethis` and `devtools` in that order and vice versa (along with redownloading RTools in case that would be helpful), but nothing seems to get this message to go away. I have no trouble running `library(usethis)` and running `usethis::` plus whatever command in the package. Despite all this, I am unable to find the Git tab in R after using the `use_git` function as advised [on this page.](https://r-pkgs.org/whole-game.html) The only thing visible in the upper right pane is this:

[image]

What else do I need to do in order to get this tab to work?

##### Edit

The Tools -> Global Option -> Git/SVN path only shows this in RStudio:

[image]

Nor does it have the option for selecting Git here:

[image]

Comment: I assume that git is installed and set to correct version  Tools->Global Option -> Git/SVN?

Comment: I tried installing `git` and it only states that it is not available for R. I also looked through the options on Tools->Global Option -> Git/SVN, but the options mentioned in other links I frequented are not available. See my edit for more details.

Comment: You need to have git installed, https://git-scm.com/download/win , not R package named `git`

Comment: I just downloaded it but I'm not seeing where this changes things for me.

Comment: Just checking you closed and restarted R after installation? If you do "which git" in the terminal what do you get?

Comment: Ah that was the ticket. I restarted my session with no fix, but closing out and returning fixed the issue. Thanks.

Comment: You are clearly still confusing RStudio with R. git integration is an RStudio issue. You tried handling it as an R issue.

Comment: why the mean tone @Roland? Glad it's sorted now Shawn

Comment: @goblinshark Why do you perceive my comment as mean? It is factual. If OP understood the difference, they could have solved the issue faster.

Comment: This is my first exposure to Git or package creation, so that is where my ignorance lies. I am familiar with what R and RStudio are, though perhaps my understanding is limited to what I have used in the past (and this is perhaps why I sound a bit unintelligent on this front). In any case, no harm in your commentary and I appreciate everyone's input. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I found usethis didn't work well with my setup. What I do to get git working is go to Project > New Project > New Directory > New Project and make sure the "Create a git repository" box is ticked. Then when you open the project the git tab should show up.

Comment: This option doesn't appear available to me. See my edit.